# Retrofit don't send the body or header (Content-type: application/json) is missed

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

retrofit, I have a problem with Rotrofit, I send with @Body all String, this String is a Object that using Gson convert it to String. With Postman copy a paste the result of Gson and it's on, but with Restrofit the server return that don't have nothing in body.

### Interface Retrofit

```
@POST("validation")
@Headers("Content-type: application/json")
Call<Validator> makeValidation(@Header("WWW-Authenticate") String token, @Body String body);
```

### The Request with Gson & Retrofit

```
            Validator validator = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Finish_Game.validator);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String validatorstring = gson.toJson(validator);


        String token = Bearer.getDefaults(Bearer.BEARER_KEY, this);
        RetrofitControler retrofitControler = new RetrofitControler();

        try {
            Call<Validator> listCall = retrofitControler.postValidationPoints(token, validatorstring);
            listCall.enqueue(new CallBackProgress<Validator>(this, this));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO for depure
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

### The simple CallBack

```
package es.iesnervion.qa.Model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.CategoriesActivity;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
 * Created by apol on 1/02/17.
 */

public class CallBackProgress<T> implements Callback<T> {
    private Context c;
    private T lisato;
    Responser res;


    public CallBackProgress(Responser r, Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        res = r;
    }

    /**
     * Invoked for a received HTTP response.
     * <p>
     * Note: An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500.
     * Call {@link Response#isSuccessful()} to determine if the response indicates success.
     *
     * @param call
     * @param response
     */
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (response.body() == null) {
            onFailure(call, new Throwable(response.message()));
        } else {
            lisato = response.body();
            String bearer = response.headers().get("WWW-Authenticate");
            res.onFinish(lisato, bearer);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected
     * exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.
     *
     * @param call
     * @param t
     */
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        //TODO solo para el depurado
        Toast.makeText(c, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        t.printStackTrace();
        res.onFailure(t);
    }
}
```

If you need something more please let me know :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just find the issue:

this:

```
Call<Validator> makeValidation(@Header("WWW-Authenticate") String token, @Body String body);
```

change to:

```
Call<Validator> makeValidation(@Header("WWW-Authenticate") String token, @Body Validator body);
```